# Форма с выпадающим списком с использованием input и select на Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Помогите реализовать поиск со всплывающим списком из объектов.
Каким образом можно объединить функционал `<input type='text'>` со списком `<select>` c использованием Vue (или если невозможно во вью, в любом другом javascript фреймворке) таким образом, чтобы из `input` происходил запрос фильтра на сервер, а данные с сервера отображались в виде списка элементов `select` как `dropdown list`, либо всплывающим окном.

Пробовал реализовать с помощью `datalist` - но это не совсем то, данная форма должна служить для выбора конкретного элемента из базы данных, и дальнейшего отображения данных этого элемента во вью, в примере элемент `station`, который имеет параметры code, name, а с помощью `datalist` возможно отобразить только имя или код. В этом плане `select` подходит идеально, выбирается именно JavaScript объект, ну а недостаток в том, что нет текстового поиска с запросом на сервер.

Один из вариантов создать 2 окна формы, один инпут, для фильра, другой `select` для выбора конкретного значения из списка отфильтрованных значений, но вариант прямо говоря уродлив.

Подскажите варианты объединить эти вещи воедино, либо вообще альтернативный вариант по типу `dropdown list` в поисковике, с действием при выборе элемента.

Пример для понимания:

```js
var station = new Vue({
  el: '#station',
  data: {
    sentStation: {
      code: '',
      name: ''
    },
    receiveStation: {
      code: '',
      name: ''
    },
    stations: [{
        code: '400409',
        name: 'Odessa'
      }, {
        code: '403002',
        name: 'Chernomorskaya TIS'
      }, {
        code: '402103',
        name: 'Chernomorsk'
      }, {
        code: '418101',
        name: 'Zhowtneva'
      },
      {
        code: '424600',
        name: 'Chernomorskaya OPZ'
      }]
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="station" class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <strong>Send station:</strong>
    <select v-model="sentStation" class="form-control">
      <option disabled value=''>Station</option>
      <option v-for="station in stations" v-bind:value="station">
        {{station.name}}
      </option>
    </select>
    <label>({{sentStation.code}}) {{sentStation.name}}</label>

    <p></p>
    <strong>Receive station:</strong>
    <input type="text" list="stationList" v-model="receiveStation.code">
    <dataList id="stationList">
            <option v-for="station in stations"
                    v-bind:value="station.code">
                {{station.name}}
            </option>
        </dataList>
    <label>({{receiveStation.code}}) {{receiveStation.name}}</label>
    <pre>
Sent station: {{sentStation}}
Receive station: {{receiveStation}}
         </pre>
  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

---

**PS** запросы фильтра на сервер я упустил для упрощения, с этими моментами уже разберусь когда форму отлажу. Благодарю за ответы.

Comment: Вам необходимо сделать кастомный dropdown, который будет состоять из input'a и выпадающего списка. По событию input - отправляйте запрос на сервер. После получения ответа - показывайте dropdown с вариантами

Comment: вот с dropdown и есть проблема, реализовал с помощью datalist, но в нем нет возможности привязать option к объекту как это реализовано в secect, только к id объекта или к названию, в примере кода получается что можно выбрать только код станции, а название не высвечивается.

Answer (score 2):

Немного поломав голову решил вопрос по другому: сделал фильтр в массиве требуемых объектов по тексту, и отфильтрованные значения уже добавил в dropdown list, если в результате поиска находит только один объект из предлагаемого списка происходит автоматическая привязка искомого значения к данному объекту. В принципе можно делать запросы на сервер, фильтровать нужный список и дальше работать с результатом. Но знакомый подсказал, что если список состоит из пару-тысяч значений то лучше его сразу загрузить весь список на страницу, ресурсов съест незначительно, а работать будет надежнее.
Результат прилагается.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:v-bind="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v-on="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/app.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>


<body>
<div id="station" class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <strong>Receive station:</strong>
        <input type="text" list="stationList" v-model="stationSearch">
        <dataList id="stationList">
            <option v-for="station in filteredStations"
                    v-bind:value="station.code">
                {{station.name}}
            </option>
        </dataList>
        <label>({{receiveStation.code}}) {{receiveStation.name}}</label>
        <pre>
Receive station: {{receiveStation}}
Station search: {{stationSearch}}
Found stations: {{filteredStations}}
         </pre>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var station = new Vue({
        el: '#station',
        data: {
            sentStation: {code:'', name:''},
            receiveStation: {code:'', name:''},
            stationSearch:'',
            stations: [
                {code: '400409', name: 'Odessa'},
                {code: '403002', name: 'Chernomorskaya TIS'},
                {code: '402103', name: 'Chernomorsk'},
                {code: '418101', name: 'Zhowtneva'},
                {code: '424600', name: 'Chernomorskaya OPZ'}
            ],
            filteredStations:[]
        },
        watch:{
            stationSearch: function(val){
                if(val.length < 3 ) return;

                var filterArray = this.stations.filter(station => checkStation(val,station));
                if(filterArray.length == 1){
                    this.receiveStation = filterArray[0];
                    this.filteredStations = null;
                    return;
                }
                this.filteredStations = filterArray;
            }
        }
    });

    function checkStation(patt,station){
        var regexp = new RegExp(patt,"i");
        return regexp.test(station.code) || regexp.test(station.name);
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```